# Specify ControlTemplate for ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, controltemplate, itemcontainerstyle

The following is similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.  However, I get the error

> Invalid PropertyDescriptor value.

on the Template `Setter`.  I suspect it's because I didn't specify a `TargetType` for the `Style`; however, I don't know the container type for `ItemsControl`.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Some Content Here" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <Button Content="Edit" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- heterogenous controls -->
    <ItemsControl.Items> 
        <Button Content="Content 1" />
        <TextBox Text="Content 2" />
        <Label Content="Content 3" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can qualify the property name with the type name:

```
<Setter Property="Control.Template">
```

The container for `ItemsControl` is normally a `ContentPresenter`, but if the child is a `UIElement` then it won't use a container.  In this case, all of the children are Controls, so the `ItemContainerStyle` will apply to them directly.  If you added an item other than a `UIElement`, that setter would set the `Control.Template` property on the `ContentPresenter`, which would succeed but have no effect.

Actually, it sounds like what you want is to wrap each child in a container, even if they are already a `UIElement`.  To do that, you will have to use a subclass of `ItemsControl`.  You could use an existing one like `ListBox`, or you could subclass `ItemsControl` and override [`GetContainerForItemOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride.aspx) and [`IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride.aspx) to wrap the items in your own container.  You could wrap them in a `ContentControl` and then use that as the `TargetType` for the `Style`.

```
public class CustomItemsControl
    : ItemsControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ContentControl();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        // Even wrap other ContentControls
        return false;
    }
}
```

You will also need to set the `TargetType` on the `ControlTemplate` so that the `ContentPresenter` will bind to the `Content` property:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
```

Comment: Works swimmingly! I was trying to do all of it with XAML, and just a few lines of code to derive a class makes it all happy, neat and clean.

Comment: "If you added an item other than a UIElement, that setter would set the Control.Template property on the ContentPresenter, which would succeed but have no effect." - I looked for ages before I found this tip!

Answer (score 3):

Also if you only want to do all of it with XAML you can simply use ListBox instead of ItemsControl and define a style for ListBoxItem:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Elements.ListViewModels}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>Some Content Here</TextBlock>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                <Button>Edit</Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Note that because I am using ListBox the container is ListBoxItem(Generally the container for WPF's default list control is always named the Item) so we create a style for ListBoxItem:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
```

Then we create a new ControlTemplate for ListBoxItem. Please note that ContentPresenter is not used as it always appears in articles and tutorials, you need to template-bind it to Content property of ListBoxItem, so it will show the content for that item.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

I just had the same problem and fixed it this way. I dont wanted some functionalities of ListBox ( item selection ) and by using this technique the item selection does not work anymore.