# How to draw a border around each element in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, itemtemplateselector

I'm using an `ItemsControl` and a `ItemTemplateSelector` to draw display the UI of my items. But now, all my elements need to be inside in a `Grid` (and one of its columns the element should be there).

At the beginning I supposed was right to have a `ContentControl` nested in an `ItemsControl`, and this `ContentControl` should have the `ItemTemplateSelector`, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff like that should be in the `Template` of the item container, for `ItemsControls` that is a bit problematic as the containers are `ContentPresenters` which have no `Template`. You could subclass `ItemsControl` [to use a `ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride), then use the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` to edit the `Template` of those containers.

Comment: thank you. I've investigated a little bit about ´GetContainerForItemOverride´ and this questions helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542381/specify-controltemplate-for-itemscontrol-itemcontainerstyle

Answer (score 1):

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lst">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="10" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="Navy">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This sets the same border width for all textboxes in the itemscontrol. Can we have border size depending on the length of the textbox.